# Max Flow/Minimum Cut - Flow after removing K edges algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was asked to develop an algorithm for the following problem :

Given :

1. A flow network G whose edges have maximum capacity of 1
2. G's maximum flow |F|
3. A positive integer K

Delete exactly K edges so that the flow of the network is minimized.

My thoughts/algorithm :

1. If K is greater than or equal to |F| delete ALL of the edges that cross G's Minimum cut
   and if K is still greater than zero delete **random edges** and the new max flow is zero
2. If K is equal to |F| delete ALL of the edges that cross G's Minimum cut
   and the new max flow is zero
3. If K is less than |F| delete **K** of the edges that cross G's Minimum cut
   and the new max flow is |F|-K

I am in need of some validation as the Max Flow/Min Cut is new to me.
Lastly the intuition behind the Max Flow/Min Cut that i got is that the Min (Source,Sink) cut works as a **"bottleneck"** to the maximum flow we can push in the network.Is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes min cut is "bottleneck" for flow, also `|Min-Cut| = Max-flow`. There's tons of proofs online if you're interested (it's known as max-flow min cut theorem).

For your algorithm there's no need to delete random edges in step one, deleting one edge from min-cut reduces max-flow by the flow that goes through that edge (in this case `1` cause all weights are `1` according to statement).

So solution is just:

1. Find any Min-cut
2. Delete `min(K, |Min-cut|` edges from the graph)

Finding Min-Cut can be done very easily:

1. Construct residual flow graph
2. Run any max-flow algorithm on it (Ford-Fulkerson, Bellman-Ford, etc)
3. Now do BFS from source node, only go through edges where flow value is less than capacity
4. Now all edges that go from visited node to unvisited node form a min-cut

Comment: So glad I got the intuition right.Thanks a lot for the help!